# Does Office365 have "App password" option?

Tags: passwords, exchange, office365

Does Office 365 have "App passwords" like Google does? Unique passwords given to applications requesting access that can be revoked?

I've looked and I don't see the option.

Edit 1: Added images of Hotmail and Business pages.

Edit 2: Ramhound pushed me to enable 2-Factor which enabled the option in Hotmail/365 Personal. I'm now looking into how to enable the feature on Exchange/365 Business.

Edit 3: Looking for "App Password" in the 365 Business Administration Console. I don't see the option after a brief look, but I'm continuing my search.

[image: 365 Business Dashboard]
[image: hotmail]
[image: business]

Comment: Yes;  Microsoft Accounts have application passwords just like Google Accounts have application passwords.  You signed into your Office 365 account using your Microsoft Credentials.

Comment: You can delete your comments.  The moderators cleaned up the unproductive noise. :-)

Comment: I am not personally going to vote for migration for one simple fact.  While `Office 365` itself is a online service, the application password element of this question, I believe is on topic.  I honestly just assumed your asking because you wanted to configure a desktop email client to work with your `Office 365` account.  There are also over a hundred questions tagged as `Office 365`.

Comment: @Ramhound I was asking because I am creating an application for work and it is using the SMTP portion of my (or someone else's) email account. For that, I'd prefer not to have my account password included - if it's in a config file as plaintext or encrypted in a database. I knew Google offered that ability, but wasn't able to find it in 365.

Comment: As such, I'm trying to use options of a service or application options in a professional manner. I'd consider that "Superuser", although if it's not, I'm more than game to move/ask the question elsewhere.

Comment: I believe this to be on topic.  People might disagree and if they do, it will get moved to the proper location, I thought it was important to explain the question in the context of a desktop application.

Comment: After some poking around, I think this question straddles the line between super-user and webapps - I'm configuring something to work with a webapp. I think I'll mark the question answered, since the original question has more or less been answered (Application Passwords in Office365 Personal is working w/2FA) although I'm now working on the expanded side of it (Office365 Business/Exchange Application Passwords, since I didn't consider them to be wholefully different at first). I'll ask the second part of the question on WebApps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the instructions in order to generate a [new application password](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/app-passwords-two-step-verification):

> The steps for generating a new app password are always the same:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Microsoft account.
> 2. Under Password and security info, tap or click Edit security info. 
>    **If you're prompted for a security code here, enter it and
>      tap or click Submit.**
> 3. Under App passwords, tap or click Create a new app password.
>
> A new app password is generated and appears on your screen.

[Multi-Factor Authentication for Office 365](http://blogs.office.com/2014/02/10/multi-factor-authentication-for-office-365/)

Comment: Hrm... is this available for both Business and personal? I'm not seeing that option anywhere under my work account.

Comment: There is indeed a difference between the `Business` and the `Personal` `Office 365` subscription services.  Your inability to do it likely is connected to your permission.  Because its been possible since [Feb 2014](http://blogs.office.com/2014/02/10/multi-factor-authentication-for-office-365/)

Comment: Added images of Hotmail (live.com) and Business (office.com). I don't see Applications Passwords on either of them. I'll ask my network tech about Business, but I'm wondering why the option isn't there for hotmail atleast.

Comment: @WernerCD - Hotmail shouldn't really exist.  Its all under a single alias `Microsoft Account` and either the email is handled by an `Outlook.com` or `Office 365`.  **Your pictures indicate you don't even have 2FA enabled.**  I assumed you knew that was required.  2FA on the Office 365 end is enabled/disabled by the Administrator

Comment: Ramhound you are really busy today. keep on.

Comment: @Ramhound Assumptions and all... I'm surprised I missed that requirement. That has Personal App Passwords available now. Waiting on network dude to get back from the field so I can inquire as too that option.